# How can I restore all my backed up data?

Tags: backup, google-backup

I wiped my old phone and got a new one today, and on my old phone I had all of Google's back-up options turned on, but it didn't sync any of my app data when I installed the apps on my new phone.

Just in case something like this happened, I also copied and pasted the files of my old phone into a folder on my PC. However, nothing changed when I copied all those files onto my new phone. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Copying and pasting folders from the old phone to the new one doesn't link it to the app installed in the new phone. Instead, try backup apps such as Titanium Backup, and make a complete backup of all the apps which you require from the old phone. Now, a folder named TitaniumBackup would be created in your SDcard. Copy that folder and paste it in the new phone. Install Titanium Backup in the new phone and try to recover the apps with data. Your issue will be resolved.

Comment: I wiped my old phone though and gave it to someone else. I thought that Google backed up your app data to their servers if you had the "App Data" sync turned on which I did

Comment: Well, in that case, you have lost all the app data permanently, as far as I know.

Comment: Is none of the app data stored in the folders that I copied?

Comment: If the app supports backup and restore feature and if the data present in folders are some kind of backups, then there is a possibility that you may recover the data back using the backup and restore functionality of the app.